# Bipartite graph as a union of disjoint edge covers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Given a bipartite graph $G$ with minimum degree $r$,
>   Prove that $G$ is the union of $r$ disjoint edge covers.

I tried to solve it but not sure about an assumption.

Assumption: The graph $G$ can be reduced to an $r$-regular graph by removing edges and at most one vertex connected to each. Ex: for the star $K_{n,1}$, remove n-1 edges and vertices to get a 1-regular graph with two vertices.

Using the assumption, remove edges and their connected vertices such that we get a $r$-regular graph. Split the regular graph into $r$ matchings and then add the removed edges and their respective vertices to the $r$ matchings.

Comment: Removing one edge from a star graph will give you one isolated vertex and a $K_{1,n-1}$ for some $n$

Comment: You are correct.  I think I'm not awake yet.

Comment: What is an disjoint edge cover? Do you mean matching? And why isnt a star a counterexample to the claim? I think it should be the maximal degree...

Comment: The edge covers are disjoint with respect to each other

Comment: @PrudiiArca In the case of a star, the minimum degree is $1$, so you are looking for just one [edge cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover), which you can take to be the set of all edges. That being said, a star is a counterexample to the assumption, since you can definitely not make it into a $1$-regular graph.